# Selection in Angular Dart material dropdown select gives error

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a component with a material dropdown select and when the [(selection)] is of type SingleSelectionModel I got an error "angular dart Expected a value of type 'SingleSelectionModel', but got one of type 'Term'". When it's of type Term it's fine.
I need SingleSelectionModel to access its changes stream and to do some operations with the selected value.

I have Dart 2.2.0, angular: ^5.2.0, angular_components: ^0.11.0.

Can anybody help how to use SingleSelectionModel for [(selection)]?

```
@Component(
  selector: 'x-plan-edit-rule',
  template: '''
    <material-dropdown-select
        [options]="terms"
        [(selection)]="selectedTerm"
        [buttonText]="buttonText">
    </material-dropdown-select>
  ''',
  directives: const [
    coreDirectives,
    MaterialButtonComponent,
    MaterialDropdownSelectComponent,
  ],
)
class EditPlanRuleComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() Rule rule;
  SelectionOptions<Term> terms;
  SingleSelectionModel<Term> selectedTerm = SelectionModel<Term>.single(); // GIVES ERROR
  //Term selectedTerm; // WORKS FINE WITHOUT ERROR

  EditPlanRuleComponent();

  @override
  ngOnInit() {
    // List<Term> rule.availableTerms
    terms = SelectionOptions.fromList(rule.availableTerms);
    selectedTerm?.selectionChanges?.listen((_) {
      // do some checks after the selection change
    });
  }


  String get buttonText =>  'Some button text';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution

I've split template binding `[()]` to `[]` and `()` so the template is

```
  template: '''
    <material-dropdown-select
        [options]="terms"
        [selection]="selectedTerm"
        (selectionChange)="validateTerm($event)"
        [buttonText]="buttonText">
    </material-dropdown-select>
  ''',
```

In Dart file I have a method `validateTerm(Term term)` which does some validation checks and assings selected term to `selectedTerm`. So I don't need to monitor selection changes stream.

```
 Term selectedTerm;

 void validateTerm(Term term) {
    // do some validations...
    selectedTerm = term;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, could you share your code in github? I'm having an error of:
`EXCEPTION: Assertion failed: org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/material_select/material_dropdown_select_accessor.dart:118:12
_select.selection == null
"Cannot set [selection] when using a Dropdown control value accessor."`

Comment: It's not possible to share the code as it's a part of very big project. As I've just checked, I use the solution described in previous answer (updated).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an error or just a normal behavior. I use `[selection]` to display the value and `(selectionChange)` to set the value. This way it works fine.

Comment: alright thanks, I successfully implemented the event.